# Is every finite, nondiscrete $T_0$ space connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Is every finite, nondiscrete $T_0$ space connected?
What I've tried is to find a separation and thus get a contradiction with the statement that the space is nondiscrete. After some time I've got lost in it. It seems so "picky".

Comment: what about $X=\{a,b,c\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset,\{a,b\},\{b\},\{c\},X\}$? The space is not discrete, $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c\}$ separate the space, but it is $T_0$

Comment: @RyleeLyman You need $\{b,c\}$ too for a topology.

Comment: Take any finite nondiscrete $T_0$ and add an isolated point to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ be endowed with topology $\tau=\{\varnothing,\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Then $X$ is $T_0$ and e.g. $\{3\}$ is a non-trivial clopen set.